# O que é linguagem simbólica no contexto de Assembly

Tags: assembly

Realizando uma lista de Organização de Computadores me deparei com a seguinte pergunta:

Reescreva os programas escritos em linguagem de montagem (assembly) no exercício anterior para linguagem simbólica. Considere
que a primeira instrução de cada programa seja “montada” na posição de memória 512 e que cada instrução ocupa exatamente 1 posição
dessa memória. Os dados são armazenados na memória a partir da posição 640 considerando o rótulo das variáveis em ordem alfabética

Encontrei problema em resolver tal atividade em razão da 'linguagem símbolica', que não sei oque é nesse contexto de OC. Pesquisando não encontrei a definição exata de linguagem símbolica no contexto de Assembly, mas encontrei [essa](https://www.quora.com/What-are-symbols-in-assembly-language) resposta no Quora que indica oque são símbolos em Assembly, mas não responde: quais símbolos representa as diretivas do Assembly, tais como `ADD`, `SUB`, etc. Nesse caso eu suponho que tenha que escrever o número da operação e o número dos operandos em binário ou uma representação fornecida pelo autor (certo ?), transformando a linguagem Assembly em algo mais 'abstrato', parecido com:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha interpretação está correta ? Se sim, na atividade nada é informado, como eu resolveria isso ?!?

Obs: Não quero que façam a atividade, quero entender como eu posso fazer.

Answer (score 4):

A linguagem de máquina normalmente é acompanhada de uma versão “legível” chamada Linguagem Simbólica ou simplesmente de Assembly.

Simbólica pois esta linguagem não é composta de números binários ou hexadecimais. A linguagem Assembly é na realidade uma versão legível da linguagem de máquina. Ela utiliza palavras abreviadas, chamadas mnemônicos, indicando a operação a ser realizada pelo processador.

Exemplo:

A instrução em Linguagem de Máquina padrão x86:

```
00000105h
```

Pode ser atribuida ao mnemônico MOV (abreviação de movement) tendo dois registradores como parâmetro, R1 e R5. Quando o processador executa essa instrução, ele comanda o movimento do conteúdo de R5 para R1.

Então a instrução em linguagem de máquina `00000105h` pode ser escrita em linguagem simbólica como:

```
MOV R1, R5
```